# echo() in MATLAB will not output desired information from java class

Tags: java, matlab, class, plugins, fiji

I have an analysis script in MATLAB that utilises MIJI and a java plugin called TrackMate. It is initialised with the following script and opens an image file to analyse.

```
% add java paths and script folder
javaaddpath '\mij.jar';
javaaddpath '\ij-1.51n.jar';
addpath '\Fiji.app\scripts';
Miji(false);

% Get currently selected image
% imp = ij.IJ.openImage('http://fiji.sc/samples/FakeTracks.tif')
imp = ij.ImagePlus('\B1R1 16000 Frames 405 561nm HILO.tif');
imp.show()
```

A model and settings object is generated which tells TrackMate how to analyse the image.

```
%----------------------------
% Create the model object now
%----------------------------   
% Some of the parameters we configure below need to have
% a reference to the model at creation. So we create an
% empty model now.

model = fiji.plugin.trackmate.Model();    

% Send all messages to ImageJ log window.
model.setLogger(fiji.plugin.trackmate.Logger.IJ_LOGGER)

%------------------------
% Prepare settings object
%------------------------      
settings = fiji.plugin.trackmate.Settings();
settings.setFrom(imp)
```

The model returns the following components when `get(model)`is called;

```
  Class: [1×1 java.lang.Class]
           FeatureModel: [1×1 fiji.plugin.trackmate.FeatureModel]
                 Logger: [1×1 fiji.plugin.trackmate.Logger$5]
    ModelChangeListener: [1 java.util.LinkedHashSet]
             SpaceUnits: 'pixels'
                  Spots: [1×1 fiji.plugin.trackmate.SpotCollection]
              TimeUnits: 'frames'
             TrackModel: [1×1 fiji.plugin.trackmate.TrackModel]
```

Of interest, is the ***FeatureModel*** component which contains the analysis output from TrackMate. When running `featMod = get(model,'FeatureModel')` the following is returned as a 1x1 FeatureModel;

```
Spot features declared:
   - QUALITY: Quality, 'Quality' (QUALITY) - double valued.
   - POSITION_X: X, 'X' (POSITION) - double valued.
   - POSITION_Y: Y, 'Y' (POSITION) - double valued.
   - POSITION_Z: Z, 'Z' (POSITION) - double valued.
   - POSITION_T: T, 'T' (TIME) - double valued.
   - FRAME: Frame, 'Frame' (NONE) - integer valued.
   - RADIUS: Radius, 'R' (LENGTH) - double valued.
   - VISIBILITY: Visibility, 'Visibility' (NONE) - integer valued.

Edge features declared:

Track features declared:
   - TRACK_DURATION: Duration of track, 'Duration' (TIME) - double valued.
   - TRACK_START: Track start, 'T start' (TIME) - double valued.
   - TRACK_STOP: Track stop, 'T stop' (TIME) - double valued.
   - TRACK_DISPLACEMENT: Track displacement, 'Displacement' (LENGTH) - double valued.
```

I can output the individual values as a java string by stating `featMod.echo()`, however this only tells me the values from the *Track features declared* component of `featMod`, and not of *Spot features declared* which is the output I need to complete my analysis.

***How do I get the values from the spot features declared component?*** I cannot figure out why it isn't giving me the desired output, but giving me other component.

When I try calling it specifically with `featMod.echo('SpotFeatures')` I get the error message;

> No method 'echo' with matching signature found for class 'fiji.plugin.trackmate.FeatureModel'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, got it solved in the image forum by user emartini https://forum.image.sc/t/problem-exporting-xml-from-trackmate-in-matlab/27242/3

The code you need to add

```
import fiji.plugin.trackmate.io.TmXmlWriter %add this import

outfile=java.io.File('F:\Projects\Matlab\Test_track_july25.xml'); %%or your file name 
writer = fiji.plugin.trackmate.io.TmXmlWriter(outfile); 
writer.appendModel( trackmate.getModel() ) %trackmate instantiate like this before 
trackmate = TrackMate(model, settings) writer.appendSettings( trackmate.getSettings() ) writer.writeToFile()
```